# My Power Steering Doesn't Work All the Time

Tags: honda, power-steering

My power steering is fine when I start the car in the morning and drive for some distance, then after awhile it'll get tighter and finally becomes like a non-powersteering car. When I take a full turn when the car is in idle, it turns extremely hard, but when I give the car gas it starts to turn more freely, respectively. My car is a Honda City 1.5exi 2001 model.

Comment: When you're sitting in idle and try to turn the wheel, does the engine making a squealing noise?

Comment: Wonder if the pump is starting to fail...

Comment: @MooseLucifer Yes i can hear a noise in low volume

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the belt isn't squealing (indicating slippage), and the fluid isn't low, and there isn't any grinding (from rack&pinion system), then it sounds like the power steering pump is failing as CharlieRB suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the fluid level isn't low and that the drive belt is tight.

Comment: I've been checking frequently,fluid level is fine, recently i've fixed all the leakages,the same issue was there before i fixed leaks and the mechanic told me that the tight will get free gradually.but it doesn't